# Multiple MQ destination in DataPower

Tags: ibm-datapower

I have a situation in DataPower where I have one MQ input and 2 MQ output to implement. I have configured a MQ FSH and trying to manage the distribution in the XSL. But dont know how to do multiple distribution.

Can someone please help

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!-- Send the message via MQ -->
    <xsl:variable name="mqURL" select="concat('dpmq://[ MQ-QM-Object ]/?RequestQueue=[ Destination-queue ]')" />
    <xsl:variable name="urlOpenResult">
        <dp:url-open target="{$mqURL}" response="responsecode-ignore">
            <xsl:copy-of select="$output"/>
        </dp:url-open>
    </xsl:variable>
```

Something like that would do it. Then you can deliver the other message out as backend connection.

Answer (score 0):

This is an extension to Anders's answer. The client to server processing rule should be as follows : Match action --> Transform --> route --> result. The transform action should be mapped to the following xsl :

```
<xsl:variable name="mqURL1" select="concat('dpmq://GateWay_ST/?RequestQueue=multi1')" />
<xsl:variable name="mqURL2" select="concat('dpmq://GateWay_ST/?RequestQueue=multi2')" />
<xsl:variable name="urlOpenResult">
    <dp:url-open target="{$mqURL1}" response="responsecode-ignore">
        <xsl:copy-of select="$output"/>
    </dp:url-open>
</xsl:variable>




    <!--Set the destination URL in the context variable--> 

    <dp:set-variable name="'var://context/mqbackend/Destination'" value="$mqURL2" />



</xsl:template>
```

In the route action use the option Use Variable to Select Destination

var://
context/mqbackend/Destination

Yes, the flow is done.